# Backingup Azure WebApp when connection string is injected through keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-backup-vault

I am using Azure Keyvault to store my connection string of a database. Using connection string options in configuration of Azure WebApps, I inject the connection string as `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://vaultlink....)` without any problems I can access the connection string on the application side.[image]

However, if i try to use WebApps Backup function while connection string is set `@Microsoft.KeyVault...`, backup fails saying that `Database connection string not valid for database secretfnlafter (SQLAzure). Keyword not supported: '@microsoft.keyvault(secreturi'.`
What is the correct way of backingup azure webapp when using kayvault for connection string

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce your issue, seems the backup does not support the connection string references the keyvault.

Comment: @JoyWang, Thanks a lot for your comment. I also came to the conclusion that it simply is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, seems the backup does not support the connection string references the keyvault.

You could post it as an idea in the azure feedback:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback